# Silent which brew?

Tags: shell, sh

For this function:

```
homebrewinstall()
{
    if which brew 2> /dev/null; then
        return 0
    else
        return 1
    fi
}

homebrewinstall
```

Always prints out the location:

```
$ /usr/local/bin/brew
```

Is there a way to have this test preform silently?

Comment: The `if` statement is redundant; `homebrewinstall () { which brew > /dev/null; }`.

Comment: Also, the built-in command `type -p brew` will accomplish the same task without running the external command `which`.

Answer (score 2):

You're using the `2>` operator, which is redirection file descriptor 2 (stderr). The `which` command sends its output to stdout. Try using `>` instead of `2>`.